# __buildin_expect and if condition behaviour

Tags: linux, kernel

- I wonder how they achieved || functionality with (&& and unlikely) in the below piece of code.

```
if (unlikely(!arch_get_random_seed_long(&v)) && unlikely(!arch_get_random_long(&v))) {
                break;
   }
```

- As per design, if arch_get_random_seed_long gets value &v there is no need to fill the value again in arch_get_random_long(). This piece of code working fine.
- But, how do 'unlikely' achieve this. Skipping the remaining code after && once [unlikely(!0)] is achieved.

Thanks,
Paavaanan

Comment: `unlikely` doesn't change the logic. An expression `unlikely(X)` is evaluated to `X` whatever X means. That is, the `if` condition is equivalent to `!arch_get_random_seed_long(&v) && !arch_get_random_long(&v)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Thanks for your comments. I agree with unlikely. But how do first half of the statement before &&  [unlikely(!arch_get_random_seed_long(&v))] only evaluated when it return 1 and 2nd part of the other instruction is safely discarded. Do unlikely branching mechanism play any role here?